# c# : Create a connect button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a login form and a button which check if the user name and the password are true.
but the problem is the code I tried .. I must click on the connect button twice.

but the code should work when I click on the button just once ! Right ?

I think the problem is:  the showDialog won't be disappeared if only I click in some button that it's DialogResult set in some value, so in the first click the connexionButton.DialogResult gets the DialogResult.OK value and in the second click the button executes the code.

***you can notice that the event simpleButton1_Click is the event for the connexionButton Button***

this is the event I used :

```
  this.connexionButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);
```

this is the code I tried :

```
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Boolean allowCnx = false;

     foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Users"].AsEnumerable())
     {
         if (row[1].ToString().ToLower() == idBox.Text.ToLower() && row[2].ToString().ToLower() == mdpBox.Text.ToLower())
         {
            allowCnx = true;
         }
     }

     if (allowCnx)
     {
         connexionButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
     }
     else
       XtraMessageBox.Show("Invalide Information", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

and this is the code I used to call this login form :

```
using (login loginForm = new login())
{
     var result = loginForm.ShowDialog();
     if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        this.Show();
     else
        this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you setting the click event handler in the xaml?

Comment: This is winforms..? why are you creating an Event Handler when all you need from what I can see is a Event for the button.. drop the button on the form double click the button in the designer and then add your code there

Comment: Jordan how can you determine that this is XAML from te code that he's displayed..?

Comment: Please describe the expected behavior vs. the actual behavior. You don't give enough details. In particular, what is connexionButton ?

Comment: Did you debug the code?Isn't hitting on first click?

Comment: @JordanKaye - WinForms doesn't use XAML.  Get with the old school!

Comment: Yeah thought I saw a xaml tag on the post. Woops.

Comment: Why are you returning the dialog result from a different button (connexionButton) than the simpleButton1?

Comment: I have modified my post check the modification

Comment: @iMortalitySX  :  the event simpleButton1_Click is the event for the connexionButton Button

Comment: "I think the problem is the showDialog won't be disappeared if only I press some button that it's DialogResult set in some value"  Can you please rephrase this sentence to make it more clear.  I am really trying to understand what you mean but this is not valid English.

Comment: @michael.mankus : I'll show you an exemple if I've a button and in it's properties I have this : `button.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;` the form which contains this button must be disappeared when I click on this button, because I run this form as a ShowDialog but when the properties set on : DialogResult.None the form won't be disappeared

Comment: @SpoonYukina: Why not set the DialogResult of the form directly, this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok.  Worth a shot at least...

Comment: @iMortalitySX because I don't want the form to be disappeared until the user name and the password are true

Comment: @SpoonYukina: It won't, you have logic that makes it so you only set the Dialog Result when true, so it shouldn't close.  Also I posted an answer, I think you may have an issue with AsEnumerable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Points to a different method than the one you posted
// (simpleButton1_Click_1 instead of simpleButton1_Click)
this.simpleButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click_1);

// This isn't simpleButton1_Click_1
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Not sure if that is your issue, but it looks like your event handler is a different method than the one you posted.  Do you have another method called `simpleButton1_Click_1` somewhere in your code and you've just gotten slightly confused?

**EDIT: In response to your changes/additions**

You seem to have some confusion over ShowDialog and DialogResult.

```
// When you launch the login form, I do not know what you intended to do with your
// calls to Show() and Close() but so long as you don't instend for them to do
// anything to the loginForm, that's fine.
using (login loginForm = new login())
{
    if (loginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        // Do stuff if logged in
    else
        // Do stuff if failed
} 

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Boolean allowCnx = false;

    foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Users"].AsEnumerable())
        if (row[1].ToString().ToLower() == idBox.Text.ToLower() && row[2].ToString().ToLower() == mdpBox.Text.ToLower())
        {
            allowCnx = true;
        }

    if (allowCnx)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // Don't set the DialogResult of a button.  Set it for the form.
    }
    else
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort; // Because we didn't succeed
        XtraMessageBox.Show("Invalide Information",
            "Erreur",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean this.connexionButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);

Comment: Okay.  Have you set a break point on the first line of your event handler?  Are you sure it isn't entering on the first click but is on the second?  Set a break point on this line: `Boolean allowCnx = false;` and make sure that what you think is happening - is actually happening.

Comment: I have modified my post check the modification

Comment: Post the code where you call ShowDialog.  I need to see that to help you.

Comment: No when I check on the button it runs a check and when this check is true it returns a true value for allowCnx and then when the allowCnx = true the form is disappeared

Comment: I didn't saw This.Close() however I didn't added it to my code I just added this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; so my check works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You are using `simpleButton1_Click_1` instead of `simpleButton1_Click`.
Infact the code should be:

```
this.simpleButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);
```

---

**EDIT :**

> yes I just forgot when I copied the event.. I mean
>   this.connexionButton.Click += new
>   System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);

I think, in this case, you should use a `bool` instead of a `DialogResult`, so try:

```
public bool AllowConnection = false;
private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Users"].AsEnumerable())
     {
         if (row[1].ToString().ToLower() == idBox.Text.ToLower() && row[2].ToString().ToLower() == mdpBox.Text.ToLower())
            AllowConnection = true;
     }

     if (!AllowConnection)
         XtraMessageBox.Show("Invalide Information", "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

And:

```
using (login loginForm = new login())
{
     loginForm.ShowDialog();
     if (loginForm.AllowConnection)
        this.Show();
     else
        this.Close();
}
```

Comment: yes I just forgot when I copied the event.. I mean `this.connexionButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);`

Answer (score 2):

Change your iterator for your rows from AsEnumerable to Rows.

FROM:

```
foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Users"].AsEnumerable())
```

TO:

```
foreach (var row in myClass.ds.Tables["Users"].Rows)
```

This may sound odd, but if there is any change to that table, anywhere, while you are iterating through your enumerable it will break your iteration.  See [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx)  This could be perhaps another process accessing this table at the same time, or using a datareader that has not completed filling the table in before the iteration starts.

Also, try to change your code to access the form's dialog result directly, instead of through the button.

FROM:

```
connexionButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

TO:

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Your code should only set that if your boolean value is set to true, so you will not be closing the form if your checks are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Form.DialogResult` to `DialogResult.OK`, not the `DialogResult` of the `Button`.

Some Code:

`this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`

Some Additional Thoughts:

- It's clearly better to build a standalone method to check for
  existence of the user. Don't do this in the `ClickEvent`. Maybe you need this method again and then you will rewrite this. This will only produce bloated code.
- Prevent Users from clicking the Button before Textboxes are filled with values.